# Bug an error when accessing a class that doesn't have access to type information

Tags: scala, scala-macros

There are some classes in the library that have an IMPORT that cannot be resolved.
For example, org.scalatest.tools.Framework in ScalaTest.

If I add scalatest as a dependent library, it will be added to the test classpath, but this import will not be resolved in the normal test classpath.
There is no SBT module in the test classpath.

```scala
import sbt.testing.{Event => SbtEvent, Framework => SbtFramework, Runner => SbtRunner, Status => SbtStatus, _}
```

I need to scan for classes under a specific package arrangement in macro and search for classes with specific features.

```scala
def collectXxx(targets: List[c.Symbol]) {
  targets.filter { x =>
    {
      x.isModule || (
        x.isClass &&
          !x.isAbstract &&
          x.asClass.primaryConstructor.isMethod
    } && x.typeSignature.baseClasses.contains(XxxTag.typeSymbol)
  }
}
```

This will filter to symbols that are object / class and inherit from Xxx.
This will work in most cases, but if there is a class in targets that cannot be compiled as is, such as scalatest, the compiler error cannot be avoided.
The moment baseClasses is accessed, the macro deployment status is set to global error.

```
[error] <macro>:1:26: Symbol 'type sbt.testing.Framework' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class org.scalatest.tools.Framework'.
[error] Make sure that type Framework is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Framework.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of sbt.testing.
[error] type `fresh$macro$612` = org.scalatest.tools.Framework
[error]                          ^
```

If you look at the stack trace in debug mode, I was setting global_error when I accessed each property of StubClassSymbol.

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubSymbol.fail(Symbols.scala:3552)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubSymbol.info(Symbols.scala:3563)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubSymbol.info$(Symbols.scala:3563)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubClassSymbol.info(Symbols.scala:3567)
  | => cat scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubClassSymbol.info(Symbols.scala:3567)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseClasses(Types.scala:2593)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.computeBaseClasses(Types.scala:1703)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.computeBaseClasses$(Types.scala:1680)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.computeBaseClasses(SymbolTable.scala:28)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.$anonfun$defineBaseClassesOfCompoundType$2(Types.scala:1781)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.memo(Types.scala:1651)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.defineBaseClassesOfCompoundType(Types.scala:1781)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types.defineBaseClassesOfCompoundType$(Types.scala:1773)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.defineBaseClassesOfCompoundType(SymbolTable.scala:28)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseClasses(Types.scala:1634)
    at refuel.internal.AutoDIExtractor.$anonfun$recursivePackageExplore$3(AutoDIExtractor.scala:119)
```

I thought of a way to get around this.
Perhaps when the import fails to resolve, that TypeSymbol becomes a StubClassSymbol.
So I parsed the structure of the Symbol that went into error and added a condition to filter it if a StubClassSymbol was found. And this one has worked.

```scala
!x.typeSignature.asInstanceOf[ClassInfoTypeApi].parents.exists { pr =>
  pr.typeSymbol.isClass && 
  pr.typeSymbol.asClass.isInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#StubClassSymbol]
}
```

But I think this is really pushy. Is there any other way around it? And I wonder if this really covers all cases.

Comment: How to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: It all plays out in this. https://github.com/giiita/refuel/blob/bf04d55606d9af7bc2a97c64016b6c64435f3331/refuel-macro/src/main/scala/refuel/internal/AutoDIExtractor.scala
We currently prevent this error by doing a recursive Stub check with `recursiveStubTesting(x: c.Type*): Boolean`, but it's very inefficient, so we're looking for another way to do it.